# List Map Layers names with geometry types

Tags: python, gis, arcpy

I am trying to write a Python Tool that shows the names of all layers with their geometry types, but when I run my code it shows all layers as Polygon only. Can someone point out where I am going wrong? I am a newbie.

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping
mxd = mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
layers = mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
desc = arcpy.Describe("C:/Program Files(x86)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.4/Reference Systems/utm.shp")
type = desc.shapeType
for lyr in layers:
    print lyr.name +" " + type
```

Comment: Be aware that there are many thousands of ArcPy questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using `type = desc.shapeType`, describing the `shapeType` of a particular shapefile. This won't tell you about the individual layers in the MXD (which you're looping through with `for lyr in layers:`).

In order to get the `shapeType` of a particular layer, `Describe` again within the loop:

```
for lyr in layers:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
    print lyr.name, desc.shapeType
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)